# What is the begin key?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts

I had been dealing with a `KeyEvent` issue. I wanted to catch the `Begin` key for a shortcut but I couldn't because the controller didn't notice. Finally I realize that I was trying to catch the wrong key. I should have to catch the `Home` key. (`KeyEvent.VK_HOME`)

I found this in the source code:

```
/**
 * Constant for the Begin key.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public static final int VK_BEGIN                    = 0xFF58;
```

What is the `Begin` key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [page of Java Community Process Maintenance Review for J2SETM 1.5.0 Beta 1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/j2se/1.5.0/jcp/beta1/) says that they added that key for solving a problem for Numpad-5 key when it is pressed and numlock is off

> **New Keycode for Numpad-5**
>
> On X-Windows, X-events are produced when the numpad-5 key is pressed
>   even when the numlock key is off. Previously, there was no Java
>   java.awt.event.KeyEvent generated in this situation. A corresponding
>   keycode has been added: java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BEGIN.
>
> The bug report associated with this change is [4850137](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4850137).

Comment: I'm confused whether you still have outstanding questions. You've identified the purpose of this key code. But then you say "*It is the best approaching that I have but this doesn't work to me*". What exactly are you trying to do and what does `KeyEvent.VK_CLEAR` have to do with it?

Comment: It is just curiosity, I want to know What is the Begin key and Why none of the keys seems to respond to this code. It is very confusing that `VK_BEGIN` exists, and I wanted to know the meaning of that constant.

Comment: Well, the documentation explains this will only work on [X-Windows systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) (e.g. Linux). So you won't be able to trigger this key event on (Microsoft) Windows.

Comment: I had asumed that X-Windows System was Microsoft Windows. What a dumb!!. That's the reason why I can't check it. I'm going to update my question. Thank you!!!